# List-style-image for footer list does not work

Tags: css, list

I'm trying to set an image as the list item marker and am using the list-style-image property to do so. Problem with that: it does not work with my footer-list, I dunno where to place it exactly in my CSS (wordpress blog), the following line seems not to work:

```
.widget ul.lcp_catlist2 li{list-style-image: url(images/lifooter.png);}
```

website-url: [filmfutter.com](http://www.filmfutter.com)

The list is based on a wordpress plugin. Maybe one can check my CSS? Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following property to the `li` selector:

```
list-style-position: inside;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `overflow:hidden` under `.lcp_catlist2 li` class. Thats it.
As this is chopping off your list image.

And if you want an alternate solution, add a `list-style-position:inside;` attribute to your `.widget ul.lcp_catlist2 li` class.

**For Instance:**

```
.widget ul.lcp_catlist2 li{
   list-style-image: url(images/lifooter.png);
   list-style-position: inside; /* Addition */
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the negative. Would appreciate if any feedbacks are provided.

Comment: I didn't give you any negative?! I much appreciate that people like you spend time to help coder-noobs like me ;)